# How can i change AWS S3 content type only for audio files

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have above 50000 files ( audio, images, pdf) on AWS S3 bucket.Now i am facing a problem with firefox. Audio file is not playing on firefox because of their content-type. Before it was working well.

Audio file works good when i change the content-type from *binary/octet-stream* to *audio/mpeg*.

The default content-type ( binary/octet-stream ) is assigned for all existing files.

I also tried s3 bucket explorer tool but there are no option to change the content-type **specifically for audio files**.

*how can i change content type only for audio files?*

*Is there any example by aws php sdk?*

Thanks in advance

Comment: i fixed this issue by s3cmd command. :)

Comment: You can self-answer your question - it would potentially be worth putting details of how you solved it in an answer so others can make use of the knowledge as well.

Comment: this is the code s3cmd --recursive modify --acl-public --add-header='Cache-Control: max-age=94608000' --add-header='content-type':'audio/mpeg' --exclude '*' --include '*.mp3' s3://bucket-name/

Answer (score 8):

I also ran into this problem, and as the author pointed out, this is the way to fix it using the `s3cmd` tool:

```
s3cmd --recursive modify                             \ 
    --acl-public                                     \
    --add-header='Cache-Control: max-age=94608000'   \
    --add-header='content-type':'audio/mpeg'         \
    --exclude '' --include '.mp3'                    \
    s3://<your-bucket-name>/                         \
```

The `--recursive modify` flag tells s3cmd to recuse into your bucket and find all files to modify; `--acl-public` opens modified files for public access; `--add-header='Cache-Control` sets the amount of time in seconds the cache can keep the file (so people getting the file from your bucket won't need to download it a second time, if the file hasn't changed). `--exclude '' --include 'mp3'` instructs s3cmd to exclude all files from the process, except the ones matching the specified pattern. Here is another example, setting all css files in your bucket to text/css:

```
s3cmd --recursive modify --add-header='content-type':'text/css' \
      --exclude '' --include '.css' s3://<your-bucket-name>/
```

If you are not sure what kind of `content-type` to specify for your specific type of file, check out this list of most common mimetypes: http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/systems/wax/wax-public-help/mimetypes.htm

Comment: This solution worked for me.   One thing to note: If you're storing sensitive data, I'd suggest adding `--encrypt` as well to use S3 server side encryption.