# s3cmd to set correct content type for image/jpeg

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, s3cmd

I have uploaded a number of directories that contain images, what is the correct way to modify the content-type to "image/jpeg" without having to re-upload the images?

I tried:

```
s3cmd modify s3://ccc-public/catalog/cropped/EP01L.jpg --add-header="Cache-Control:max-age=1296000" --mime-type="image/jpeg" --recursive -vvv
```

but the Content-Type always comes as binary/octet-stream

any advise much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s3cmd has recently (as in, this past weekend) fixed this, but the code is not yet upstream.  Please try with this branch:

https://github.com/mdomsch/s3cmd/tree/bug/content-type

With a little more testing, this will get merged into upstream.

Then, your command should work exactly as you expect.
-mdomsch, s3cmd maintainer

Answer (score 3):

These days, it is recommended to use the official [Amazon Command Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

The [`aws s3 cp`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) command includes options for specifying mime-type, but by default the mime type of a file is guessed when it is uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this recently as well and used some of the info here [How can i change AWS S3 content type only for audio files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201477/how-can-i-change-aws-s3-content-type-only-for-audio-files)

For us, it came down to ensuring that you change the content-type with the following

```
--add-header='content-type':'image/png'
```

I want to emphasize using the lower case content-type vs Content-Type here.  That's what ended up making a difference.

Answer (score 2):

--add-header did not help for me. But the below worked.

```
s3cmd put style.css -m 'text/css' s3://mybucket
```